# Creating LINQ Query Objects

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to plot three different sets of data points (GraphPoints, GraphPoints1, GraphPoints2) on y axis Canvas JS graph but when I add all these sets on the Controller code, the results are not plotted. If I add just one set (e.g. y=s.GraphPoints1), then the graph is generated and the results are plotted. However, I want all the sets of data points (GraphPoints, GraphPoints1, GraphPoints2) on the y-axis on one graph. I am having troubles putting the sets of data points (GraphPoints, GraphPoints1, GraphPoints2) under y. Please someone help and let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

This works:

```
 public ActionResult Graph(int machineId)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseModel())
    {
        var sheets = db.Checksheets
            .Where(s => s.MachineId == machineId)
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
                y = s.GraphPoints                   
            });

        return Json(sheets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This does not work but I want something like this with all the sets of data points on one graph:

```
 public ActionResult Graph(int machineId)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseModel())
    {
        var sheets = db.Checksheets
            .Where(s => s.MachineId == machineId)
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
                y = $"{s.GraphPoints} {s.GraphPoints1} {s.GraphPoints2}"
            });

        return Json(sheets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here's the SQL table where the Graph Points are recorded:

```
 GraphPoints           GraphPoints1        GraphPoints2
    50                     45                   60
    30                     12                   100
    56                     89                   67
```

Comment: What does "not work"? Can you please be more specific? Do you get errors? Unexpected results? What did you expect instead?

Comment: I am trying to plot three different sets of data points (GraphPoints, GraphPoints1, GraphPoints2) on y axis Canvas JS graph but when I add all these sets on the Controller code, the results are not plotted. If I add just one set (e.g. y=s.GraphPoints1), then the graph is generated and the results are plotted. However, I want all the sets of data points (GraphPoints, GraphPoints1, GraphPoints2) on the y-axis on one graph. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, what does your table structure look like? Sample rows of data?

Comment: @Matt I am trying to create a Canvas JS graph. Please see my updated code above for more details.

Comment: y=s.GraphPoints1 generates the graph but y = $"{s.GraphPoints} {s.GraphPoints1} {s.GraphPoints2}" does not generate anything. But I want all the GraphPoints on my graph in the Y-axis.

Comment: What is `s.Graphpoints`, `Graphpointts1` and `Grahoints2`?

Comment: The GraphPoints are calculated values that I want on the y-axis of the graph that I'm trying to generate. All these GraphPoint values are recorded on a SQL table and look something like the one shown above in my updated code. Also please refer to the Controller part of my code above to see how I calculated the GraphPoints, GraphPoints1 and GraphPoints2.

Comment: How do you add these GraphPoints, GraphPoints1 and GraphPoints2 in the Select query above?

Comment: See documentation [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/label/)
`y` is number not a string. Can you paint what kind of chart you want?

Comment: @gkardava GraphPoints, GraphPoints1 and GraphPoints2 are not numbers but variables that have been calculated on the Controller part of the code (see above), although the results are numbers. I have attached a picture of how the graph would look like (again see updated code above). I hope someone can help me write the LINQ Select Query!

Comment: can you try something like this: 
`.SelectMany(s => new[]
            {
               new{ label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
                y = s.GraphPoints},
                new{ label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
                y = s.GraphPoints1},
                new{ label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
                y = s.GraphPoints2}
            });
`

Comment: @gkardava Thanks for your response! I'll try that. For now I am using the Concat method that seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The Concat method can be used to bring all the GraphPoints under y.

```
  public ActionResult Graph(int machineId)
  {
using (var db = new DatabaseModel())
{
    var sheets = db.Checksheets
        .Where(s => s.MachineId == machineId)
        .ToList()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
            y = s.GraphPoints
        });
         var sheets1 = db.Checksheets
        .Where(s => s.MachineId == machineId)
        .ToList()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
            y = s.GraphPoints1
        });
         var sheets2 = db.Checksheets
        .Where(s => s.MachineId == machineId)
        .ToList()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            label = $"O: {s.OrderNum} P: {s.PartNum}",
            y = s.GraphPoints2
        });

    return Json(sheets.Concat(sheets1).Concat(sheets2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Why do you `ToList` before the select?

Comment: Because it's creating a dropdown list from the machineId table.